# Reason for huge slowdown usinf TF Dataset API

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, dataset

I'm trying to generate batches for triplet loss where there are always pairs in the batch. The code below achieves this but it's very, very slow. In particular the choose_from_datasets method seems to be the source of the slowness.

Is there something wrong with my code that's creating the slowdown? Or is there a smarter way to do this?

I tried switching to sample_from_datasets instead, but this didn't help.

```
def batch_pairs3(dataset, num_classes, shuffle=True, num_classes_per_batch=10, num_images_per_class=2):
    # Isolate each class into its own dataset
    datasets = []
    for cl in range(num_classes):
        this_dataset = dataset.filter(lambda xx, yy: tf.equal(tf.reshape(yy, []), cl))
        if shuffle:
            this_dataset = this_dataset.shuffle(100)
        datasets += [this_dataset]

    # if shuffle:
    #     random.shuffle(datasets)
    selector = tf.contrib.data.Counter().map(
        lambda  x: generator3(x, num_classes, num_classes_per_batch, num_images_per_class))
    selector = selector.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets(datasets, selector)

    # Batch
    batch_size = num_classes_per_batch * num_images_per_class
    return dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

tf data pipeline does not handle these kind of applications where you are processing your data on the fly by iterating through it very well, unless you can independently map every data point to do such processing. For what you are doing, you may be better off pre-processing and storing your data, in something like tfrecord format and then using the data pipeline to read it in an optimized way.

Refer this official example, which kind of works on a similar problem involving triplet loss: [Time Contrastive Networks](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/tcn/README.md), [the data provider](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/tcn/data_providers.py#L293)